# Outlook 2010 backing up emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

My hard drive recently started going bad but before it went out I was able to copy most of my files off of it. I had Office 2010 using an exchange server. I had backed up my emails into a local folder in Outlook so the exchange server wouldn't delete them after its retention policy. I looked at `F:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` but the only large file I see is an .ost file. From the [MS/Office help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010354943.aspx#_Outlook_Data_File) it says:

> **Outlook Data File (.ost)** The .ost file is synchronized with the items
>   on the server that runs Exchange. Because your data remains on the
>   Exchange server, you can re-create this .ost file on your new computer
>   without having to back up the .ost file.

. This doesn't seem like where my emails would be kept, but I don't see any other promising large Outlook files. Can they even be imported back into Office 2013?

Comment: Your looking for a .PST file.  If you don't have that file your are out of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Office 2010 kept it in the Users' root directory (`F:\Users\username\`) as `Outlook_Local.pst` :)

Comment: Awesome that you found it, but it would be helpful to future users if you could describe how you found the .pst file. Were you able to look up the path from Outlook?

Comment: I got desperate and looked for any pst file in the Users directory! Sadly the Office help files are outdated and have the incorrect path

Comment: Ah. I think you can create `*.pst` files anywhere. They seem to go to `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Outlook Files` by default for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your .PST could be hidden. It sounds like you've clearly gotten past some hidden file obstacles, but this thread indicates there may be another hurdle:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/where-is-location-of-outlookpst-file-in-windows-7/6ccb1e5e-d4b5-4822-907f-c5db275374c8

Specifically, RicardoMedel's reply from Sept 27 2010.